# Looping an xml parser till a tag is done

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I'm trying to pull information from a xml file and this is the code which I'm currently developing to make it work.

```
private void parseXML(XmlPullParser parser)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    int eventType = parser.getEventType();

    Map<String, Map<String, Double>> sports = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Double>>();

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        String name = null;
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String sportName = null;
            boolean paid = false;
            Map<String, Double> preset = null;

            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    preset = new HashMap<String, Double>();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    name = parser.getName();
                    if (name.equals("sport")) {
                        sportName = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
                        paid = Boolean.parseBoolean(parser
                                .getAttributeValue(1));
                    } else if (name.equals("preset")) {
                        // TODO figure out how to loop this so it finished up the sport and then moves on to the next one
                        String presetName = parser
                                .getAttributeValue(0);
                        double value = Double.parseDouble(parser
                                .nextText());
                        preset.put(presetName, value);
                        parser.next();
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    name = parser.getName();
            }
            sports.put(sportName, preset);
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the xml its pulling the information from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sports>
    <sport name="Baseball" paid="false">
        <preset name="Pitching Mound">726.0</preset>
        <preset name="Base Distance">1080.0</preset>
    </sport>
    <sport name="Basketball" paid="false">
        <preset name="NBA Free Throw Line">181.08</preset>
        <preset name="NBA 3pt Line">265.8</preset>
    </sport>
    <sport name="Cricket" paid="true">
        <preset name="Cricket Pitch">2012.0</preset>
    </sport>
</sports>
```

What the code essentially does is getting the sport name, whether it is a paid feature or not, and the presets I have defined for it. What I'm trying to do is make the part, where it adds a preset to the preset map, loop till the end of the sports presets. I'm not 100% comfortable with using the xml parses because I get confused with using it. I tried getting the attribute count when the code gets the name of the sport, and then looping it but it didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the android docs saying its recommended to use XmlPullParser you can use parser of your choice.

To get attribute you can use `parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name")` coz you have  `<preset name="Pitching Mound">`. Name is the attribute.

To get the text use `text`.

There is a example in the docs. It has separate methods for each tag while the method is the same.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

You can use the below for reference.

```
public class XMLPullParserHandler {

    private String text;

    public XMLPullParserHandler() {

    }



    public Void parse(InputStream is) {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
        XmlPullParser parser = null;
        try {
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            parser = factory.newPullParser();

            parser.setInput(is, null);

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("sports")) {

                    }
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("preset")) {
                        Log.i(".......","Attribute value is"+parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                    }


                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = parser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("sports")) {
                        // add employee object to list

                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("sport")) {
                         // no value

                    } 
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("preset")) {
                       Log.i("Preset is",text);

                    } 
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Log Output

```
03-25 02:03:00.412: I/Attribute value is(1119):  Pitching Mound
03-25 02:03:00.412: I/Preset is(1119): 726.0
03-25 02:03:00.412: I/Attribute value is(1119):  Base Distance
03-25 02:03:00.422: I/Preset is(1119): 1080.0
03-25 02:03:00.422: I/Attribute value is(1119):  NBA Free Throw Line
03-25 02:03:00.422: I/Preset is(1119): 181.08
03-25 02:03:00.422: I/Attribute value is(1119):  NBA 3pt Line
03-25 02:03:00.422: I/Preset is(1119): 265.8
03-25 02:03:00.422: I/Attribute value is(1119):  Cricket Pitch
03-25 02:03:00.422: I/Preset is(1119): 2012.0
```

Edit:

To get the attribute paid just add the below in `case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:`

```
 else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("sport")) {
          Log.i("Attribute value is"," "+parser.getAttributeValue(null, "paid"));
 }
```