# Xmlparser.getText() is giving null

Tags: java, android, xml, android-xmlpullparser

I'm trying to pull values from a preset  xml file and I keep getting null when I try to check what the value was.

```
if (pulled.equals("preset")) {
    presetName = xmlParser.getAttributeValue(null,"name");
    Log.d(TAG, presetName + " = " + xmlParser.getText());
}
```

This is the xml im Pulling the value from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sports>
    <sport name="Baseball" paid="false">
        <preset name="Pitching Mound">726.0</preset>
        <preset name="Base Distance">1080.0</preset>
    </sport>
    <sport name="Basketball" paid="false">
        <preset name="NBA Free Throw Line">181.08</preset>
        <preset name="NBA 3pt Line">265.8</preset>
    </sport>
    <sport name="Cricket" paid="true">
        <preset name="Cricket Pitch">2012.0</preset>
        <preset name="Testing">0.8</preset>
    </sport>
</sports>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: i answered it before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626450/looping-an-xml-parser-till-a-tag-is-done and it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On XmlPullParser api, the getText() method has the following description:

> Returns the text content of the current event as String. The value
>   returned depends on               current event type, for example for
>   TEXT event it is element content (this is typical   case when next()
>   is used). See description of nextToken() for detailed description of
>   possible returned values for different types of events.
>
> NOTE: in case of ENTITY_REF, this method returns the entity
>   replacement text (or null   if not available). This is the only case
>   where getText() and getTextCharacters() return      different values.

So based on this description, first you have to check if the current xml node is TEXT in order that getText() doesn't return null.

```
if (pulled.equals("preset")) {
    presetName = xmlParser.getAttributeValue(null,"name");
    if (xmlParser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
       Log.d(TAG, presetName + " = " + xmlParser.getText());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps,